# Lm-sensors can't find fans on a Acer Laptop

Tags: 11.04, acer, fan

I have installed Ubuntu 11.04 32bit on my Acer 7750g laptop, and very thing works like a charm except the fan which keeps running.

I researched on Google and found that perhaps I need to install lm-sensors. I did very thing according to the relative posts that I had googled. But the result of sensors-detect was only one driver `coretemp'. Then the result of sensors was:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +47.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0002
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 1:       +49.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0004
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 2:       +50.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0006
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 3:       +47.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

And then I could not go any further.

Question 1: my CPU is intel i7 2630QM, but why only 4 cores are detected?

Question 2: why can't I find sensors of fans?

I have tried with lm-sensors 3.2.0 and 3.3.0. And I have read [this](http://ubuntunewb.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-control-fan-speed-on-ubuntu.html) , [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=42737).

Comment: and these:  [3]: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2780
  [4]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto
  [5]: http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Documentation

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU only has 4 cores, but 8 hardware threads (2 per core).

Fan control under Linux is painful. You might like to watch a video of Matthew Garrett from the last LinuxConf AU to understand more of the problems faced by developers. He's the main guy for Linux laptop support from what I understand.

Linky: http://blip.tv/linuxconfau/making-laptops-work-with-linux-4738042

Answer (score 0):

In my, admittedly somewhat limited experience, many laptops either don't have fan sensors or they are not detected by lm-sensors. Regardless of the cause, the end result is - you can't control fan speeds.

Comment: but my laptop works perfectly with Windows 7, i.e., the fan is off when idle or light load.

Comment: ...but is there any way to control it's speed in W7?

Comment: I mean windows can, Ubuntu cannot.

Answer (score 0):

## Try [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc)

Mine is an Acer Aspire E5-573G nothing else worked to control the CPU fan, but [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/First-steps). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The exact profile for my model is missing, but nbfc worked fine with another similar profile (Acer Aspire E5-575G). If you don't know which profile to use, you can try:
`mono nbfc.exe config -r`

You will need the latest mono version to build it on Ubuntu 18.04, so don't forget to read [How to build NBFC on ubuntu](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/How-to-build-NBFC#ubuntu).

Also I edit the default profile to turn the fan policy more agressive.

Good luck.

Comment: See more here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1267308/252684