# fans detect by lm-sensors ( acer laptop)

Tags: 18.04, acer, fan, temperature, lm-sensors

My problem is same as [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49594/lm-sensors-cant-find-fans-on-a-acer-laptop#)  but about another acer laptop (aspire vn7 591G ) . 
after google it cant to find useful solution . 
I decided try alternative way via windows , so in windows ( my system is dual boot ubuntu & windows 10 ) try to install [speedfan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpeedFan) and run it . but same issue!!! even speedfan could not to detect my fans .

SO that i realized that dont let detecting fans to opertiong system ( linux or widows ) .

```
1-did I get it right?
2-cause of this issue?
  2.1-is there any solution for it?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `fancontrol` which is part of `lm_sensors`. Install lm-sensors:

```
sudo apt install lm-sensors
```

and configure it like [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control) has been suggested.

Comment: i know . but fancontrol work when fans detected .

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'it87': No such device

Answer (score 0):

## Maybe you can use [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc)

My laptop is an Acer Aspire E5-573G nothing else worked to control the CPU fan, but [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/First-steps). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The exact profile for my model is missing, but nbfc worked fine with another similar profile (Acer Aspire E5-575G). If you don't know which profile to use, you can try:
`mono nbfc.exe config -r`

Comment: how to install it in ubuntu?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira Sorry, I saw your question only today. You can find a complete tutorial here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/482766/how-do-i-know-my-fan-is-working-in-ubuntu/1267308#1267308